# UIImagePickerController- Twitter Framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter, uiimagepickercontroller

I am having problems using choosing an image from my camera roll and assigning it to a new Tweet Sheet using the new Twitter framework.  I can easily compose a new Tweet Sheet, that isn't an issue.  I have managed to gain access to the camera roll and assign the chosen image to a UIImageView but when I select the image I want it to immediately bring up the Tweet Sheet with the image already in it.  To gain access to the camera roll I am using;

```
- (void) selectImage
{
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
    [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType =
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                              nil];
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
    }
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
NSString *mediaType = [info
                       objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
    UIImage *image = [info
                      objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    imageView.image = image;
    imageView.hidden = YES;

    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into [ShareKit](http://www.getsharekit.com/)? It makes FaceBook and Twitter integration drop dead easy, among other services.

Comment: I don't wish to use Sharekit. My app is an existing iOS 5 application making use of the new Twitter framework. I am just trying to add this one piece of functionality into it